# Searching for a site for asking for validating or rejecting strange news!

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have seen one Telegram post about three strange places in Russia which could be seen here: [Strange things at Russia country](https://vimeo.com/507146064)

I guess that video is not real and at least two of three shown places in it are fake and the last place could be a gas or oil land.

So I like to know about proper SE site or others sites for asking to become more sure about validating or rejecting the realness of this kind of news.

Comment: What is *"Telegram"*? *[Telegram Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software))*?

Comment: Like to what (the last sentence)? Please respond by [editing your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/360425/edit), not here in comments (without "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: [Foam concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam_concrete) can have a density below that of water, so the first claim is not far off.

Comment: @P.Mor & forgot Clay Shirky_q, i have updated the question, I added the missed **what** word at **like to ...**.

Comment: Off-site, one place to validate news and claims is https://www.snopes.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it counts as a [notable claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/864/26375), you can try [Skeptics Stack Exchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to check their [Help Center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting; they understandably have rather strict quality guidelines. It's rather hard to practice *scientific* skepticism if you don't have the right material to work with.